# Дублирование ответов бота сообщества / callback vk api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Пишу бота для сообщества на php, используя callback api. Проблема в том, что на каждый мое сообщение бот сразу отправляет один ответ, и спустя несколько секунд снова присылает его же (от 6 секунд где-то до нескольких минут дублированное сообщение получаю).. Искал ответ в поисковике, пишут что нужно отправлять вк ответ 200, и строку "ok". Делаю так:

```html
  $event = _callback_getEvent();
  try
  {
 switch ($event['type'])
 {
   case 'confirmation': { _callback_handleConfirmation(); break; }//Подтверждение сервера
   case 'message_new':
   {
     vkApi_messagesSend($event['object']['user_id'], "Привет!");
     header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
     echo "ok";
     exit;// !
  break;
   }
   default:  { file_put_contents('123.log',  "default!!!\n", FILE_APPEND); break; }
 }
  }
  catch (Exception $e) { log_error($e); }
  //
  _callback_okResponse();


function _callback_okResponse() { header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); _callback_response('ok'); }

function vkApi_messagesSend($peer_id, $message, $attachments = array())
{
  $random = rand(1, 1000000);
  return _vkApi_call('messages.send', array(
    'peer_id'    => $peer_id,
    'message'    => $message,
    'random_id'  => $random,
    'read_state' => 1,
    'attachment' => implode(',', $attachments)
  ));
}
```

Суть именно в case 'message_new' -- отправляю ответ, ставлю ответ 200, строку "ok", но бот флудит снова тем же сообщением спустя время. В чем может быть проблема? Буду очень благодарен за помощь, несколько дней уже пробую разные вариации кода, и всё безрезультатно пока(

Answer (score 0):

На странице настроек сервера в управлении сообществом можно посмотреть неудавшиеся запросы и их причину.

Скорее всего, скрипт выводит помимо ok что-то еще, например warning или какую-то ошибку, из-за этого ответ считается неверным.

Comment: Я это проверял тоже) При дублировании ответов никаких ошибок во вкладке "Запросы" нет.. Скрин того что происходит -- https://pp.userapi.com/c846523/v846523092/9d22/28UPRS1QNKs.jpg

Comment: @ВасилийШайдюк по умолчанию ошибки не выводятся. там нужно отфильтровать на ошибки